# Problem with sonarqube on android studio main branch empty

Tags: android, sonarqube

i have the following problem:

I want to use sonarqube to analyze my android code, whe i run the scan with the command:

`gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/`

The project page in sonarqube show me a message that say:

`The main branch has no lines of code.`

How can i push my code to the main branch to be analyze?

Comment: Are you scanning the main branch. If yes, then Use this analysis property **sonar.sources=.**

Comment: where do i use that? in sonar.properties?

Comment: Here like this `gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/, -Dsonar.sources=.`